# what is wrong with this code getElementbyId not detecting radiobutton?

Tags: html, onclick, radio-button

i want on clicking a radiobutton a list must be shown listing country/products

on clicking the radiobutton function check() is successfully called
but it seems document.getElementById('c') is not returning the element here

```js
 function check(){
               
           // var rad=document.getElemensByName('analysis');
           // alert(); // successfully executing-------------1
            if(document.getElementById('c').checked===true)
            {
                //alert();                //this one is not running--------2
                document.write('<p>Country:');
                document.write('<select>');
                document.write('<option>Select</option>');
                document.write('<option>India</option>');
                document.write('<option>England</option>');
                document.write('<option>America</option>');
                document.write('</select>');
                document.write('</p>');
                
            }
            else
            {
                if(document.getElementById('p').checked===true){
                    document.write('<p>Product:');
                        document.write('<select>');
                            document.write('<option>Select</option>');
                            document.write('<option>Mobile</option>');
                            document.write('<option>kitchen</option>');
                            document.write('<option>Shirt</option>');
                        document.write('</select>');
                    document.write('</p>');
                 }
                
            }
           
        }
```

```html
 
 Country
<input type="radio" id="c" name="analysis" value="Country" onclick="check()">
 Product 
<input type="radio" id="p" name="analysis" value="Product" onclick="check(); ">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistyped the function name; you wrote `getElemensById` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

You've written `getElemensById` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

`getElemensById` should be replaced by `getElementById`. There is no built in function in JavaScript with this name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want 
I changed it onclick to onchange
and get the element by name

```js
 function check(){
               
           // var rad=document.getElemensByName('analysis');
           // alert(); // successfully executing-------------1
     if(document.getElementsByName("analysis").value = "Country")
     {
     //alert();                //this one is not running--------2
                document.write('<p>Country:');
                document.write('<select>');
                document.write('<option>Select</option>');
                document.write('<option>India</option>');
                document.write('<option>England</option>');
                document.write('<option>America</option>');
                document.write('</select>');
                document.write('</p>');
     }
     else if(document.getElementsByName("analysis").value = "Product")
     {
     document.write('<p>Product:');
                        document.write('<select>');
                            document.write('<option>Select</option>');
                            document.write('<option>Mobile</option>');
                            document.write('<option>kitchen</option>');
                            document.write('<option>Shirt</option>');
                        document.write('</select>');
                    document.write('</p>');
     }
}
```

```html
Country
<input type="radio" id="c" name="analysis" value="Country" onchange="check()">
 Product 
<input type="radio" id="p" name="analysis" value="Product" onchange="check()">
```